# How to compare Dataset with List(Of Int64) using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, dataset

I am working on an application where I am returning a list of integers that I need to compare with a dataset in which those Ids are present. I need to filter only those ids from a dataset that I have returned from API. Here is my code

```
  Dim response = Await mKubotaInvoiceHistoryApi.GetKubotaInvoiceLocationIdentitiesAsync()
  mLocations = UIC.Cache.GetSimpleLocation()
```

> /// API Method

```
   Public Async Function GetKubotaInvoiceLocationIdentitiesAsync() As Task(Of List(Of Int64))
                Dim response = Await sendGetAsync(Of List(Of Int64))(
                    "api/partners/kubota/kubotainvoicehistory")
                Return response
            End Function
```

In response I am receiving a list of Ids and **mLocations** is a dataset as shown in the below image.

[image]

For example, If the response contains integers ids of 1 and 2 then it will remove all other locations except from location with ids 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem. Here is the code

```
  Public Sub RemoveRowsFromDataset(dataset As DataSet, columnName As String, valuesToKeep As List(Of Int64))
            dataset.Tables.Cast(Of DataTable)().ToList().ForEach(Sub(table) If table.Columns.Contains(columnName) Then table.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow)().Where(Function(row) Not valuesToKeep.Contains(CInt(row(columnName)))).ToList().ForEach(Sub(row) row.Delete()))
            dataset.AcceptChanges()
        End Sub
```

> Calling the above function

```
Dim locationIdentities = Await mKubotaInvoiceHistoryApi.GetKubotaInvoiceLocationIdentitiesAsync()
    
'Get Lookups and add in the blank values.
 mLocations = UIC.Cache.GetSimpleLocation()
'Remove This records which are not present in locationIdentities.
 RemoveRowsFromDataset(mLocations, "LocationId", locationIdentities)
```